# If $f_1,...,f_k$ are given holomorphic functions and $f$ is such that $f_i/f$ is holomorphic then $g_1f_1 + \cdots + g_nf_n = gf$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, ideals, riemann-surfaces

Say $f_1,...,f_k$ are given holomorphic functions, on, say, $\mathbb{C}$ (I'm working in a noncompact Riemann surface but it doesn't matter, $\mathbb{C}$ will do). Let $f$ be a fixed holomorphic function such that the order of $f$ at any point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is equal to the minimum of the orders of $f_1,..f_n$, in other words, $f_i/f$ is always holomorphic for any $i = 1, \dots, n$. Now let $g$ be any holomorphic function. I want to show that there exist holomorphic functions $g_1,...,g_n$ such that $g_1f_1 + \cdots + g_nf_n = gf$. That's all I want, and I would love a bit of guidance please.

This is part of a bigger problem I'm working on and it seems true but for some reason I'm not seeing it...? Is the argument simple?

Comment: You surely need some sort of condition to avoid all the $f_k$ vanishing at a point.

Comment: I don't think so, because if they all vanish then f also vanishes so it's fine

Comment: Well not quite, for instance if the ord of $f$ is $1$ and that of all the $f_{i}$'s is 2, for instance they we have a problem since any linear comb will have order atleast $2$.

Comment: May be you want to assume that $ord(f)$ is exactly the min of all the orders of the $f_{i}$'s

Comment: Yes, I do sorry

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of $f$ is the minimum of the $f_i$'s, you can write 
$$
f=f_iu
$$
with $u$ a unit in $\mathcal{O}_z$ for some $i$.  But then the ideal $(f)\subset(f_1,f_2,...,f_n)$. Hence for any holomorphic function $g$, there are $g_j$'s holomorphic so that near $z$
$$gf=g_1f_1+g_2f_2+...g_nf_n\;.$$

Comment: I don't understand. The OP's question requires $g$ to be aribitrary.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the $i$ changes as the point changes. In that case $f/f_{i}$ need not be a unit.

Comment: @harmonicuser Yes, you're right. I misread the question -- this answer only shows that this is true near the point $z$, of course.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a unit in $\mathcal{O}_z$? Also, is that your notation for the stalk at $z$ of the sheaf of holomorphic functions or something?

Comment: I do want this to hold globally :)

Comment: @ActonGrey Yep. That's the stalk. As harmonicuser pointed out, this doesn't work globally.